# How to visualize choropleth with temporal component in browser

Tags: carto, mapbox-gl-js, choropleth

I have a vector dataset with monthly water risk data per river basin. The data is available for each month (January - December) and I would like to visualize this in a browser. The geometries are constant (river basins do not change).

The  data is  structured as two files:  a shapefile with unique identifiers and a .csv file with the unique identifiers, month and value.

The preferred way to display one month of data is using choropleths. I think a very powerful way to visualize the temporal component is to have a time slide and "play" button.

I've looked at [Torque JS](https://github.com/CartoDB/torque), [Mapbox GL JS](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) however the examples do not include choropleth examples. I can imagine other people might've solved this challenge already.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[CARTO VL](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/) can render animated polygons, not a lot of code is involved but it depends on how much interactivity you need on your application. At the library documentation you have [this example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-hurricane-harvey) about animating polygons and then this other about adding [playing controls](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-add-animation-controls).

**Disclaimer**: I work at CARTO

Comment: Is this approach loading the geometries for each iteration or will it update the rendering? My geometries are appr. 70MB (15000 geometries), however it takes a long time to load. I'm getting too many request errors: 429

Comment: I might have to put this into a separate question. My geometries are static and my data is updated each month. I would like to fade-in to the new month. I only need one layer and my guess is that currently the old layer is maintained. My script can be found here: https://github.com/rutgerhofste/cartovl_animation_test

Comment: And rendered: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rutgerhofste/cartovl_animation_test/master/test.html

Comment: yes this is for another question and more related with query performance, but a hint is that you may want to add indexes to your JOIN fields. Since you are enterprise client you may also want to contact our team directly (even I love when clients post questions on GIS SE to increase the public answers database).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [Leaflet Time Dimension](http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/) if you don't mind replicate the geometries you can convert your data into a time-enabled geojson like in the [Oil Spill Simulation](http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example15.html) and then render each time step like a chorophlet map.